# Conversion pytorch to coreml for element-wise maximum operation

Tags: python, pytorch, coreml, coremltools

I tried to convert a PyTorch model to coreml with the element-wise maximum operation based on coremltools.

With torch.max operation, I got

```
ValueError: node input.2 (max) got 2 input(s), expected [3]
```

With torch.maximum operation

```
RuntimeError: PyTorch convert function for op 'maximum' not implemented.
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide some additional code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same issue in conversion with pytorch element-wise operation to coreml model, but solved it by adding support for torch.maximum and torch.minimum for the MIL converter with the torch frontend.

```
@register_torch_op
def maximum(context, node):
    inputs = _get_inputs(context, node)
    x = inputs[0]
    y = inputs[1]
    out = mb.maximum(x=x, y=y, name=node.name)
    context.add(out)
```